# How to return a 2d dynamically allocated array from a function in C

Tags: c, return, malloc

I have dynamically allocated an array inside a function inside another function and filled it with values and am now attempting to return it to "main". I know similar questions have been asked on this site and others but none of them have worked for me or applied to my specific situation.

Here is a sample of the relevant code:

```
double *JacobiSolver(int N,int it,double f[][N]) {

    double (*un)[N+2] = malloc((N+2)*sizeof(*un));

    for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++) {
            un[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    printf("----------------------------------------------------------"); //printing solution after it iterate
    printf("Approx Solution after %d iterations:  \n",it);
    for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++) {
            printf("%.3lf ",un[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------- \n");

    return *un;
}

double *discretization(int N,int a,int b,int it) {

    double *un;
    //create f
    un = JacobiSolver(N,it,f);

    return *un;
}

int main() {
    int N = 10; //grid size
    int it = 10; //number of iterations to perform

    int a = -1;//domain
    int b = 1;

    double un;
    un = discretization(N,a,b,it);


    printf("Printing un \n");
    printf("------------\n");
    for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++) {
            //printf("%.3lf ", *( *(un + i) + j) ); This is what i tried but commented out because it causes errors
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("----------------\n")

    return 0;
}
```

(There is more going on in these functions but it is quite long so I removed everything not relevant). Not sure if this is relevant but I am compiling with gcc on a Linux machine. Any help with this would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this for hours.

I expected an output of un being printed to the terminal but I receive an error of `poissoneq_jacobi.c:112:33: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’) 112 |             printf("%.3lf ", *( *(un + i) + j) );`

Comment: FYI, the code you share here does not compile - the compiler complains about variable "someValues" not being defined.  Please include a minimal code example that will compile so that others can evaluate it and offer suggestions.

Comment: @NoDakker I apologize, the 'someValues' was meant to indicate I'm modifying this array. I edited it so it should compile now.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comment about revising your minimal code to allow it to compile, I copied and pasted your example to give it another try at compiling.  The compiler still tossed out errors with the code with missing bits of information.  But instead of just trading comments back and forth about what may need to be done to get it to compile, I went ahead and did a bit of refactoring in order to get the code to compile.  Following are some code snippets illustrating the tweaks I did to get it to compile (and maybe to assist anyone else trying to help you with a solution.

First off, I corrected a couple of compiler complaints in the "discretization" function as noted by the corrections and comments.

```
double *discretization(int N,int a,int b,int it) {

    double *un;
    //create f
    double f[N][N];             /* To take care of first compiler error */

    un = JacobiSolver(N,it,f);

    //return *un;               /* To take care of second compiler error */
    return un;
}
```

A placeholder definition of a two-dimensional array named "F" was added, and the return statement was changed to return the address pointer and not the value at address "un".

Then, within the "main" function, a correction was made to the double variable pointer declaration so that it would properly receive the pointer from the call to the "discretization" function.

```
    //double un;
    double *un;                 /* To take care of third compiler error */
```

At that point, the program does compile.

After that, I examined your statement indicating that the "printf" statement was causing errors.  Here is where I may be not be clear in my interpretation of what type of printing is to occur, but it appears that the "for" loops are attempting to increment the address pointer via row and column and then print the value of what is at the derived pointer.

If that is the case, following is some refactored code that I think more clearly illustrates what is to happen.

```
printf("Printing un \n");
printf("------------\n");
/*
for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++) {
        //printf("%.3lf ", *( *(un + i) + j) ); This is what i tried but commented out because it causes errors
    }
    printf("\n");
}
*/
/* Looks like this is trying increment the matrix address and then print the value at the derived address */
/* Warning - I might have incorrectly assumed what you want to do here and gone off on a tangent          */
for (int i=0;i<N+2;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<N+2;j++) {
        printf("%.3lf ", *un ); /* Print the double value at the derived address */
        un += 1;                /* Increment column by one */
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("----------------\n");
```

Following are the key bits.

- The initial "for" loop and "printf" block was commented out.
- The "printf" statement then prints the value found at the address location.
- Within the inner "for" loop of the refactored loop block, the address counter keeps getting incremented by a value of "1" address location instead of attempting to perform some type of address incrementing within the "printf" statement.

Again, this bit of refactoring is based on what I interpreted what was being attempted with the "for" loop block.  If that is not the case, please ignore this part.

Following was the terminal output from a test run of this refactored code.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Jacob/bin/Release$ ./Jacob 
----------------------------------------------------------Approx Solution after 10 iterations:  
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
--------------------------------------------------------- 
Printing un 
------------
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

For sure this is not the total solution for your code, but hopefully, it gets you past your roadblocks.  Go ahead and try this out to see if it meets the spirit of your project.